# Is it possible to get rid of garbage collector in java by implementing java reference as shared_ptr?

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection

It seems reasonable to implement java reference as a shared_ptr and don't use garbage collection at all.

Comment: that's what they did in Python, but Python is effectively single-threaded and that makes a big difference for garbage collection.

Comment: Nope, you would need `weak_ptr` to avoid cyclic references and even _too_ much use of `shared_ptr` is not efficient and would affect performance unless you have some lazy kind of deallocation mechanism.

Comment: Technically, you will have ref-counting garbage collector then. Which have not so great perfomance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, it is not efficient at all.

The Oracle's JVM did used reference counting GC in the past, it was slow and not effective. They switched to more modern GC algorithms like generational GC algorithms.

Do not that shared_ptr is acceptable in c++ out of the sheer fact that the vast majority of objects in c++ are allocated in the stack, so the reference counting nature of shared_ptr is barely noticeable. On Java, the vast majority of objects are allocated in the heap, so you'd think twice before you start counting them.